# My window air conditioner is making a high pitched sound. Does it need to be oiled?

Tags: air-conditioning

We bought a new window air conditioner last year or the year before and by the end of last summer, a high-pitched sound could be heard coming from it. I’m thinking it needs to be oiled?

In the past, I’ve had air conditioners torn apart in my living room because they needed extensive cleaning. This is a huge chore partly because I don’t think the manufacturer intended for the unit to be opened or cleaned. Since these units hang outside windows they collect anything the wind happens to blow into them. Why don’t they use a fine screen like a window screen on these to keep them from collecting all the debris that they do?

After cleaning a few of these out I considered installing screens but was afraid to lest I find out why they don’t have them to the detriment of the machine. I’ve never seen cleaning or oiling instructions on any window air conditioner I’ve owned. Have I just missed them? This noise troubles me because it’s a large unit and it’ll be a monumental task to remove it from the window (a ladder must be used) and then open it all up far enough that I can get oil to whatever needs it. Moving it will be a two-person job and sometimes that second person is hard to come by.

I’m hoping someone will tell me about some magic method that can be used while the air conditioner is still in the window and still under its metal casing.

Comment: A modern air conditioner is probably not made with oiling as an option, so what you should do is contact the warranty folks while it's still in warranty. If you let the warranty expire over the winter without addressing this, that's on you.

Comment: If facing replacement, a (good) mini-split will be far more efficient, and keeps all the "whatever blows into them" outside where it can easily be hosed off (with an open hose so as not to bend the fins with a high-pressure nozzle.) Plus, it does not take up a huge amount of window space.

Comment: Remember some of the junk blows by but you can catch it with a filter (screen) and plug the filter up quicker.